# Centos 7 connection timeout for all web services and SSH

Tags: centos, timeout, firewall, iptables

After recovering iptables config I encountered an issue with connection timeouts to my centos server. I can access my website with no problem (though it loads unusually long), but accessing any other exposed service is impossible - including WordPress cockpit which throws error 523.

Affected key iptables rules:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 60 -j ACCEPT # SSH custom port
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT # Webmin custom port
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Short description:
connecting to server via SSH is impossible - when using my standard login I'm stuck at `/etc/issue.net` message and password prompt doesn't even appear - after 30 seconds I'm getting connection timeout/closed by foreign host warning. If I try login as a root (which technically shouldn't be possible due to ssh config), I can go past the password prompt, but then the rule kicks in and it won't let me in as this user.

In case of Webmin, loading login screen alone takes around 30 seconds. Navigating within Webmin is almost impossible and it ends in "session expired" warning after which I can't reauthenticate due to timeouts/connection issues and have to navigate back to login screen, otherwise I won't be able to proceed further.

Question is - how can I resolve this problem? I use to my adventage the fact, that after accessing a certain tab in Webmin I have approx. 30 seconds before the mentioned above warning pops out, so I can change one thing at a time (though applying ACCEPT policy in "Linux IPFirewall" for some reason doesn't work despite clicking the appropriate button). Restoring server image won't do me any good since iptables rules will be flushed again and only DROP policy stays, which prevents me from accessing the machine.

EDIT. I forgot to mention that I'm using Cloudflare as a proxy of my server as well as its DNS servers. Maybe this have something to do with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that whole problem was incorrect iptables rules order.